# parts of mesh not moving with bone

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

When i move the bone, parts of the mesh wont move with it. I have tried to assign the faces to the bones and that didn't work for some reason. I have weight painted it countless times and it still did not fix the problem. I have remodeled the finger and tried to reposition the bones and watched countless tutorials. here's the video to the problem. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fbx8RXMY6w8

Comment: Read up about Weight Painting in Blender. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/sculpt_paint/weight_paint/index.html#weight-paint and specifically [this](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/sculpt_paint/weight_paint/usage.html#vertex-groups-for-bones) section.

Comment: some vertices are probably not part of the correct vertex group, please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: https://blend-exchange.com/b/zq0l1eRS

Answer (score 0):

It looks like some vertices are not correctly assigned. First thing put the Armature modifier at the top of the modifiers stack:

[image]

Now in the *Armature* modifier enable the 2 first options, they will allow you to see the mesh in *Edit* mode as deformed by the modifier:

[image]

Now select the buggy vertex and assign it to the correct vertex group (for this one it's probably *Hand IK R*):

[image]

Comment: Ah i see know, I forgot rearranging the modifiers changes the mesh or something like that. Thank you